# Cold Reset STC125A60S2 PLC Board

Tags: microcontroller, power-supply, reset, plc, board

I am working on these PLC Board: http://more-suns.com/product/html/?321.html but I cannot contact manufacturer. The fact is to have it programmed I have realized that I can only do it after a cold reset (power-on reset), but to get a really good cold start I have to turn off power for several hours.
The datasheet of the STC12C5A60S2 MCU inside the board indicates that, I think, some capacitor is charged and needs to get discharged.

How can I get a really cold start without that waiting?. I have installed a pilot light in parallel to the board, but still nothing.

Thanks for your advices.

Comment: It sounds like the problem and power storage are both internal to the PLC. You may have to reverse engineer and modify it. That or perhaps a firmware update will remove the need to cold reboot it for programming?

Comment: that was i am doing rigth now

Comment: reading again the manual, i found out that those STC MCU have an MAX810 integrated, the questios is if i can add an external MAX810 to the RESET pin, so i can be sure to have POR (Power On Start)?